# JQuery UI Custom Tabs that need to fit horizontal space

Tags: css, jquery-ui

JQuery UI Tabs are stacked left and do not fill the horizontal space.

Perhaps this is too much to ask, but here it goes:

Consider the following markup

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      ...content...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...content...
    </td>
    <td>
      ...content...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By default table cells expand to fit the horizontal space available. So, if the tabs were designed as table cells, it would be fluid.

Questions:

1. Is this behavior possible using DIVS?
2. Is this possible using Jquery UI Tabs?

Regards, Serendipity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, using CSS:

```
.ui-tabs-nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-tabs-nav li {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```